# File error while running the tutorial06 "Networks from OpenStreetMap" from FLOW project

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sumo, flow-project

I'm learning the FLOW project and doing their tutorial06 "Networks from OpenStreetMap". In this tutorial, one should be able to use the .osm file to run the simulation. However, there is an error raised, that the .xml of the network config files are missing.

The code in jupyter-notebook is as following:

```
# the TestEnv environment is used to simply simulate the network
from flow.envs import TestEnv

# the Experiment class is used for running simulations
from flow.core.experiment import Experiment

# all other imports are standard
from flow.core.params import VehicleParams
from flow.core.params import NetParams
from flow.core.params import InitialConfig
from flow.core.params import EnvParams
from flow.core.params import SumoParams

from flow.networks import Network

net_params = NetParams(
    osm_path='networks/bay_bridge.osm'
)

# create the remainding parameters
env_params = EnvParams()
sim_params = SumoParams(render=True)
initial_config = InitialConfig()
vehicles = VehicleParams()
vehicles.add('human', num_vehicles=100)

flow_params = dict(
    exp_tag='bay_bridge',
    env_name=TestEnv,
    network=Network,
    simulator='traci',
    sim=sim_params,
    env=env_params,
    net=net_params,
    veh=vehicles,
    initial=initial_config,
)

# number of time steps
flow_params['env'].horizon = 1000
exp = Experiment(flow_params)

# run the sumo simulation
_ = exp.run(1)
```

and I got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-4a3adf64a06c> in <module>
     13 # number of time steps
     14 flow_params['env'].horizon = 1000
---> 15 exp = Experiment(flow_params)
     16 
     17 # run the sumo simulation

~/Desktop/flow/flow/core/experiment.py in __init__(self, flow_params, custom_callables)
     79 
     80         # Create the environment.
---> 81         self.env = create_env()
     82 
     83         logging.info(" Starting experiment {} at {}".format(

~/Desktop/flow/flow/utils/registry.py in create_env(*_)
    128             })
    129 
--> 130         return gym.envs.make(env_name)
    131 
    132     return create_env, env_name

~/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py in make(id, **kwargs)
    154 
    155 def make(id, **kwargs):
--> 156     return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
    157 
    158 def spec(id):

~/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py in make(self, path, **kwargs)
     99             logger.info('Making new env: %s', path)
    100         spec = self.spec(path)
--> 101         env = spec.make(**kwargs)
    102         # We used to have people override _reset/_step rather than
    103         # reset/step. Set _gym_disable_underscore_compat = True on

~/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py in make(self, **kwargs)
     71         else:
     72             cls = load(self.entry_point)
---> 73             env = cls(**_kwargs)
     74 
     75         # Make the enviroment aware of which spec it came from.

~/Desktop/flow/flow/envs/base.py in __init__(self, env_params, sim_params, network, simulator, scenario)
    162         # use the network class's network parameters to generate the necessary
    163         # network components within the network kernel
--> 164         self.k.network.generate_network(self.network)
    165 
    166         # initial the vehicles kernel using the VehicleParams object

~/Desktop/flow/flow/core/kernel/network/traci.py in generate_network(self, network)
    125         elif self.network.net_params.osm_path is not None:
    126             self._edges, self._connections = self.generate_net_from_osm(
--> 127                 self.network.net_params)
    128         else:
    129             # combine all connections into a list

~/Desktop/flow/flow/core/kernel/network/traci.py in generate_net_from_osm(self, net_params)
    577 
    578         # collect data from the generated network configuration file
--> 579         edges_dict, conn_dict = self._import_edges_from_net(net_params)
    580 
    581         return edges_dict, conn_dict

~/Desktop/flow/flow/core/kernel/network/traci.py in _import_edges_from_net(self, net_params)
    841         net_path = os.path.join(self.cfg_path, self.netfn) \
    842             if net_params.template is None else self.netfn
--> 843         tree = ElementTree.parse(net_path, parser=parser)
    844         root = tree.getroot()
    845 

~/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in parse(source, parser)
   1194     """
   1195     tree = ElementTree()
-> 1196     tree.parse(source, parser)
   1197     return tree
   1198 

~/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in parse(self, source, parser)
    584         close_source = False
    585         if not hasattr(source, "read"):
--> 586             source = open(source, "rb")
    587             close_source = True
    588         try:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/anjie/Desktop/flow/flow/core/kernel/network/debug/cfg/bay_bridge_20200623-1345091592912709.4246037.net.xml'
```

I guess that, the in FLOW project, they try to use the 'netconvert' from SUMO to convert .xml files to the sumoconfig files. However, it fails at this step, that the .osm cannot be converted. But still, I cannot fix the error. BTW, the previous 5 tutorials can be run correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of this question. After investigating for hours, I found that the problem is the following command:

```
netconvert --osm bay_bridge.os

Error: Cannot import network data without PROJ-Library. Please install packages proj before building sumo
Quitting (on error).
```

Therefore, the problem is that the SUMO is not built with PROJ, and then I tried to re-build the SUMO with PROJ. However, I always encounter the problem with proj_api.h, which is not found by the ./configure command, but exists in /usr/local/includes/.

Thus, I looked into the config.log file from sumo source files, and it said:

```
configure:12501: checking proj_api.h usability
configure:12501: g++ -c -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -std=c++11 -O2 -DNDEBUG   conftest.cpp >&5
In file included from conftest.cpp:59:
/usr/local/include/proj_api.h:37:2: error: #error 'To use the proj_api.h you must define the macro ACCEPT_USE_OF_DEPRECATED_PROJ_API_H'
   37 | #error 'To use the proj_api.h you must define the macro ACCEPT_USE_OF_DEPRECATED_PROJ_API_H'
```

So I open the proj_api.h with root and edit the line as follows:

```
#ifndef ACCEPT_USE_OF_DEPRECATED_PROJ_API_H
//#error 'To use the proj_api.h you must define the macro ACCEPT_USE_OF_DEPRECATED_PROJ_API_H'
#define ACCEPT_USE_OF_DEPRECATED_PROJ_API_H 1
#endif
```

After all this, I successfully built the SUMO with the PROJ and everything works fine!